# Reversing the order of a MatchCollection from regex?

Tags: c#, collections, reverse

I'm wanting to get matches from a string in regex, then using `MatchCollection`, reverse the order of matches.

Currently, I have the following:

```
var pattern = @"\(([^)]*)\)";
var results = Regex.Matches(value, pattern);
if (results.Count > 1)
{
 results = (MatchCollection)results.Cast<MatchCollection>().Reverse();
}
```

Which gives the following error:

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'd__75`1[System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection]' to type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection'."}

Is there a way of doing this? It should be noted I have tried all StackOverflow solutions and none work in my case.

Comment: If you are using Cast<T>, it should have the singular parameter as the T type. So `results.Cast<Match>().Reverse()`. Also i believe MatchCollection should already have LINQ Reverse. Are you sure you included System.Linq?

Comment: I'm definitely using LINQ, it seems MatchCollection doesn't have this functionality. `results.Cast<MatchCollection>().Reverse();` like so also returns the same error

Comment: I used `Cast<Match>` not `Cast<MatchCollection>` A syntax mistake?. It works when i test with it.

Comment: VS then tells me to change `results.Cast<Match>().Reverse()` to `(MatchCollection)results.Cast<Match>().Reverse();`

Comment: Ah that is because you re-assigning back into results. It is not possible to convert Match array to MatchCollection. Use a different variable if you can.

Comment: What is the purpose of reversing? And why isn't `List<Match>` or `Match[]` sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Match> matchList = matchCollection.Cast<Match>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Index).ToList();
```